# How to convert Spark RDD to Spark DataFrame

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have working with `Spark 3.1.2`  with `Scala 2.12`. I want to parallelize some keys among nodes and they read its data based on the key which receive. So, I must work with `RDD` first and then convert it to `Spark DataFrame`. I read data from the table in `Oracle Database`. The code is in the following:

```
   object managementData extends App {
     val num_node = 2
    def read_data(group_id: Int):String =  {
       val table_name = "table"
       val col_name = "col"
       val query =
         """ select f1,f2,f3,f4,f5,f6,f7,f8
            | from """.stripMargin + table_name + """ where MOD(TO_NUMBER(substr("""+col_name+""", -LEAST(2, LENGTH("""+col_name+""")))),"""+num_node+""")="""+group_id
      val oracleUser = "ORCL"
      val oraclePassword = "XXXXXXXX"
      val oracleURL = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@//X.X.X.X:1521/ORCLDB"
      val ods = new OracleDataSource()
       ods.setUser(oracleUser)
       ods.setURL(oracleURL)
       ods.setPassword(oraclePassword)
      val con = ods.getConnection()
      val statement = con.createStatement()
      statement.setFetchSize(1000)      // important
      val  resultSet : java.sql.ResultSet = statement.executeQuery(query) //
      val ret = Iterator.continually(resultSet)
         .takeWhile(_.next)
         .flatMap(r => (1 until 8).map(i => r.getString(i)))
         .mkString(" ")
      return ret
    }
 def udf(rdd: RDD[String]): DataFrame = {
      val spark = SparkSession
         .builder.getOrCreate()
      val schema = new StructType()
         .add(StructField("f1", StringType, true))
         .add(StructField("f2", StringType, true))
         .add(StructField("f3", StringType, true))
         .add(StructField("f4", StringType, true))
         .add(StructField("f5", StringType, true))
         .add(StructField("f6", StringType, true))
         .add(StructField("f7", IntegerType, true))
         .add(StructField("f8", IntegerType, true))
      val df = spark.createDataFrame(rdd, schema)
      return df
      }
    def main():Unit={
        val group_list = Seq.range(1,2,1) // making a list
        val conf = new SparkConf()
           .setMaster("local[2]")
           .setAppName("testScala")
           .set("spark.executor.memory", "8g")
           .set("spark.executor.cores", "2")
           .set("spark.task.cpus","1")
        val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
        val rdd = sc.parallelize(group_list,num_node)
           .map(read_data)
        rdd.map(x => println(x)).collect()
        udf(rdd)
     }
     main()
    }
```

`read_data` works perfectly. But, I cannot convert `RDD` to `Spark DataFrame` and receive this error:

```
 overloaded method value createDataFrame with alternatives:
  (data: java.util.List[_],beanClass: 
  Class[_])org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame <and>
  (rdd: org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD[_],beanClass: 
  Class[_])org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame <and>
  (rdd: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[_],beanClass: 
  Class[_])org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame <and>
  (rows: java.util.List[org.apache.spark.sql.Row],schema:  org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType)org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame <and>
  (rowRDD: org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD[org.apache.spark.sql.Row],schema: org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType)org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame <and>
  (rowRDD: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[org.apache.spark.sql.Row],schema: org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType)org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
   cannot be applied to (org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String], org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType)
val df = spark.createDataFrame(rdd, schema)
```

Would you please guide me what is wrong about `createDataFrame` method to convert RDD to Spark Dataframe?

Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: Not sure I am following it all.

Answer (score 1):

Need this type of approach:

```
...
val schema = new StructType()
  .add(StructField("f", StringType, true))
  .add(StructField("m", StringType, true))
  .add(StructField("l", StringType, true))
  .add(StructField("d", StringType, true))
  .add(StructField("g", StringType, true))
  .add(StructField("v", IntegerType, true))

val df = spark.createDataFrame(rdd, schema)
```

Comment: Dear @thebluephantom, thank you for your answer. Would you please guide what type I can use for ```spark``` variable? It does not let me define ```val spark = SparkSession.builder.getorcreate()```.  I receive this error: **overloaded method value createDataFrame with alternatives**.

Comment: Collect not needed

Comment: Does not look correct your code in the question.

Comment: I update my question and show the complete code. Would you please take a loot at it? Many thanks.